# make simple 2 way socket qt

Tags: python, qt

I'm new to QT and I'm trying to create a simple tube with reading and writing in QT.

This is the code for me:

```
 QTcpSocket socket;
 socket.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 1234);
 socket.write("hello from qt code"); // this line seems to work
 qDebug() << socket.bytesAvailable(); // this return alwise 0
 QByteArray res = socket.readAll(); // this not working ( i get nothing)
```

I picked up a simple Python server from the other side ,which sends everything back to the QT client ,
This is my simple python server (just for you have the full picture):

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 
PORT = 1234             
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print data
    conn.send("\x09\x08\x07\x06\x05\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05")
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

for some reason I manage to send "hello from qt code" to the server without any problem, but in my QT code I can not get anything, why is that?

thanks
yoko

Comment: This post does not seem to have anything to do with `c++`, so please remove the `c++` tag and add a `python` tag instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully sure if this will help but you certainly should make some ready-check for data to read.

f. e. [bool QAbstractSocket::waitForReadyRead(int msecs)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForReadyRead)

After checking the documentation i haven't find that instantly casting `qDebug() << socket.bytesAvailable();` will catch the bytes.

For every multidevices/asynchronous action there shall always be some "check gates", which will tell if we are on the right spot in the right time.

Additionally i encourage to do some check after connecting to host (also reading the entry for QAbstractSocket can support), method below will be helpful:
[bool QAbstractSocket::waitForConnected(int msecs)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected)

Comment: it's actually fix this problem - wired... when i put sleep it didn't fixed it , maybe using this function make the buffer flush...